# How to send a request in node to an endpoint that uses grpc-web-proto?

Tags: node.js, http, request, http-post, grpc-node

I am trying to send an http request to this endpoint using the request library from npm, however, how would I send that payload as shown in the
screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a client that uses grpc-web and a Node server that uses one of the Node gRPC libraries, those use different protocols so you will need to use a proxy to translate between them. For example, [this grpc-web documentation page](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/web/basics/#configure-the-envoy-proxy) describes how to configure an Envoy proxy for that purpose.